# How do I find the all valid pairings between two sets?

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, algorithm

I have a pretty hard problem to solve here, and I have no idea how to start. I have X kind of fruits and 5 colors (let's say `Red`, `Green`, `Yellow`, `Blue` and `Purple`). Each fruit can be available in several colors (but in at least 1). How can I find each combination, when I need exactly 1 fruit of each color but no fruit twice (so there will always be bought exaclty 5 fruits in exactly 5 different colors)?

For example:

1. Pears are available in [Red, Green, Yellow]
2. Apples are available in [Red, Green]
3. Plums are available in [Purple]
4. Grapes are available in [Red, Green, Purple]
5. Bananas are available in [Blue, Yellow]

Since bananas are the only fruit available in `Blue`, it's already sure, that bananas will be bought in `Blue`, and not in `Yellow`.

These would be the solution for this list:

1. `Yellow Pear`, `Red Apple`, `Purple Plum`, `Green Grapes`, `Blue Banana`
2. `Yellow Pear`, `Green Apple`, `Purple Plum`, `Red Grapes`, `Blue Banana`

No other combination is possible here. Is there any algorithm to do this with a dynamic list, which may also have more than 5 fruits?

I know, it's a pretty hard problem, but maybe someone has a simple solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this small size problem with brute force:

```
fruit = {pear, apple, plum, grape, banana};
col = {{r, g, y}, {r, g}, {p}, {r, g, p}, {b, y}};
mp = MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}] &, {fruit, col}]
```

where `mp` gives the candidate selections. Selecting and displaying solutions:

```
Row[Grid[#, Frame -> True] & /@ 
  Select[Tuples[mp], Sort[#[[All, 2]]] == {b, g, p, r, y} &]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I guess I can make it work with this solution, but could you please explain what this script is actually doing? I'd like to understand it and not only use it :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SoBiT The answer only supplies an approach for the small problem. Tuples[mp] above just generates all the possible combinations choosing each fruit. The core of the second part selects from this list the element which has distinct colours.

Comment: And this solution also avoids duplicated entries, right?

Comment: @SoBit  I am not sure what you mean by duplicates: the solutions are distinct. The ways lists are created and selected distinct fruits and colours. Would have to change for larger or more complex problem.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming) for this. Let the vector of fruits be:

```
fruits = {
    "Red Pear", "Green Pear", "Yellow Pear", "Red Apple", "Green Apple",
    "Purple Plum", "Red Grapes", "Green Grapes", "Purple Grapes",
    "Blue Bannas", "Yellow Banans"
};
```

Then,the constraint that there are at least 5 different fruits means that the following matrix must be positive:

```
{
{1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1}
}
```

The constraint that there are at least 5 colors means the following matrix must be positive:

```
{
{1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}
}
```

The objective function will be:

```
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

meaning that the number of total fruit is to be minimized (it is possible one might need more than 5). Here is the [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming) call that solves this:

```
lp = LinearProgramming[
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {
    {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
    {1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}
    },
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    0,
    Integers
]
```

> LinearProgramming::lpip: Warning: integer linear programming will use a machine-precision approximation of the inputs.
>
> {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}

So, one answer is:

```
Pick[fruits, lp, 1]
```

> {"Yellow Pear", "Green Apple", "Purple Plum", "Red Grapes", "Blue Bannas"}

Comment: Really nice :-)

Answer (score 3):

An even shorter solution using [`ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BacktrackSearch):

```
fruits = <|
   pears -> {red, green, yellow},
   apples -> {red, green},
   plums -> {purple},
   grapes -> {red, green, purple},
   bananas -> {blue, yellow}|>;
AssociationThread[Keys[fruits], #] & /@
 ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"][Values[fruits], DuplicateFreeQ, 
  DuplicateFreeQ, All]

(** {
 <|pears -> yellow, apples -> red, plums -> purple, grapes -> green, bananas -> blue|>,
 <|pears -> yellow, apples -> green, plums -> purple, grapes -> red, bananas -> blue|>
} **)
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct an edge list from given information and use [`FindIndependentEdgeSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html):

```
fruits = {pear, apple, plum, grape, banana};

colors = {{Red, Green, Yellow}, {Red, Green}, {Purple}, {Red, Green, 
    Purple}, {Blue, Yellow}};

edges = Flatten @ MapThread[Thread @* UndirectedEdge, {fruits, colors}];

FindIndependentEdgeSet @ edges
```

[image]

```
Graph[edges, GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding",  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

To get all matchings, we can use [this method by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187307/125):

```
lg = LineGraph[edges];

edges[[#]] & /@ FindIndependentVertexSet[lg, 
     Length /@ FindIndependentVertexSet[lg], All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
fruit = {"Pear", "Apple", "Plum", "Grape", "Banana"};
col = {{Red, Green, Yellow}, {Red, Green}, {Purple}, {Red, Green, 
    Purple}, {Blue, Yellow}};
```

The information about `fruit` is sort of encoded in `col` where a restricted set of colors is available to choose from for each element in `fruit`.

```
Column /@ col
```

[image]

The permutations over this set will have a limited number of elements compared to a brute-force method that will give `5!` or `120` choices.

```
{3 2 1 3 2, Times @@ Length /@ col}
```

> {36, 36}

```
(interimX = Outer[List, Sequence @@ col] // Flatten[#, 4] &)
res = Select[interimX, DuplicateFreeQ]
```

[image]

Now threading this color information with `fruit`:

```
Thread[{#, fruit}] & /@ res // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it as a Boolean SAT problem with `FindInstance` / `SatisfiabilityInstances`. The annoying `SymbolName` remapping stuff is because Mathematica does not like variables that are not a single symbol e.g `x[y]` when SAT solving, so I create `x$y` to get around this:

```
Remove["Global`*"];

onehot[list_List] := BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, Length@list] @@ list

(* relation: a fruit must have exactly 1 colour *) 
relation[fruit_, cols_List] := onehot[Thread[fruit[cols]]];

(* The relations *)
rels = {
   relation[pear, {red, green, yellow}],
   relation[apple, {red, green}],
   relation[plum, {purple}],
   relation[grape, {red, green, purple}],
   relation[banana, {blue, yellow}]
   };
sys = And @@ rels;
vars = BooleanVariables[sys];

(* Group by colours, and apply onehot constraint to each colour group i.e for all red things, only one fruit-red combination can be true *)
c = And @@ (onehot /@ GatherBy[vars, #[[1]] &]);

(* tedious variable name remapping because of FindInstance not liking compounded terms *)
varRemap = AssociationThread[vars, 
   Symbol[SymbolName[#[[0]]] <> "$" <> SymbolName[#[[1]]]] & /@ vars];
invRemap = KeyValueMap[#2 -> #1 &, varRemap];

(* State the final expression and solve when true *)
expr = (sys && c) /. varRemap;

(* sols = FindInstance[expr, BooleanVariables[expr], Booleans, 100]; *)

(* Show all the true assignments for each solution set, and put the variables back to their nice compound form *) 
With[{v = BooleanVariables[expr]},
  Pick[v, #] & /@ SatisfiabilityInstances[expr, v, All]] /. invRemap

(* finalform=BooleanConvert[c&&sys,"CNF"] *)

(** {{apple[green], banana[blue], grape[red], pear[yellow], plum[purple]},
     {apple[red], banana[blue], grape[green], pear[yellow], plum[purple]}} **)
```