# Find all perfect matchings of a Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to find all perfect matchings for some bipartite graphs. For example

```
    Graph[{1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 8, 5, 7}, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 3 <-> 4, 
    3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 8, 5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 8, 5 <-> 2, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 2, 
    7 <-> 4}]
```

Now I can use

```
    FindIndependentEdgeSet[%]
```

which indeed gives me a perfect matching, but it does not give me all. Is there a way to easily find all perfect matchings?

Comment: *Counting* perfect matchings of a bipartite graph is equivalent to computing the permanent of a 01-matrix, which is **#P**-complete (thus there is no easy way in this sense).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick way to program this is through finding all maximum independent vertex sets of the line graph:

```
lg = LineGraph[g];
EdgeList[g][[#]] & /@ 
 FindIndependentVertexSet[lg, Length /@ FindIndependentVertexSet[lg], All]
```

```
HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ %
```

[image]

Comment: What if you want to include the non-perfect ones as well? You can take subsets?

Comment: I used Flatten[Subsets[#] & /@ edges, 1] where edges=EdgeList[g][[#]] & /@ 
 FindIndependentVertexSet[lg, Length /@ FindIndependentVertexSet[lg], All], then HighlightGraph[g,%]

Comment: This only works if there are perfect matchings to begin with ... otherwise, the program suggested will only give maximum matchings, which may not be perfect ... am I correct?  There is a function that finds a maximum matching in a graph in IGraph, it would be nice if it could be asked to find any given number of them, or All (which may be unfeasible if there is too many of them ... the number of them grows very quickly ...

Answer (score 5):

I've implemented the algorithm given in the paper

[Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac97web.pdf).

This algorithm takes as input a directed bipartite graph and should give a list of all perfect matchings as output.

```
EnumPerfectMatchings[G_] := 
 EnumPerfectMatchingsIter[G, FindIndependentEdgeSet[G]]

EnumPerfectMatchingsIter[G_, M_] := If[
  Length[EdgeList[G]] == 0,
  {M},
  Module[{DGM, DM, DG, NewM, c, e, Gp, Gm, p},
   DM = M;
   DG = DirectedEdge @@@ 
     Reverse /@ List @@@ Complement[EdgeList[G], M];
   DGM = Graph[VertexList[G], Join[DM, DG]];
   c = FindCycle[DGM];
   If[Length[c] != 0, c = Flatten[c], Return[{M}]];
   c = Transpose@Partition[c, 2];
   If[MemberQ[DG, c[[1, 1]]], c = Reverse[c]];
   c = {c[[1]], DirectedEdge @@@ Reverse /@ List @@@ c[[2]]};
   NewM = Join[Complement[M, c[[1]]], c[[2]]];
   e = c[[1, 1]];
   p = List @@ e;
   Gp = Graph[Complement[VertexList[G], p], 
     Select[EdgeList[G], Intersection[List @@ #, p] == {} &]];
   Gm = Graph[VertexList[G], Complement[EdgeList[G], {e}]];
   Join[EnumPerfectMatchingsIter[Gm, NewM], 
    Map[Append[#, e] &, 
     EnumPerfectMatchingsIter[Gp, Complement[M, {e}]]]]
   ]
  ]
```

For the graph given in the question it returns the correct result 0.007 sec on my machine.

Comment: Trying to run this in M11.3 will blow up my session irreparably

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it does the same for me now too. I seem to remember it working quite well at the time. I do not think it will be very useful to find out what has changed in the meantime, since your posted answer is much more concise anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following code:

```
points = {1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 8, 5, 7};
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 6, 3 <-> 8, 
          5 <-> 6, 5 <-> 8, 5 <-> 2, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 2, 7 <-> 4};

tmp=Table[FindIndependentEdgeSet[Graph[i, edges]], {i,Permutations[points]}]// DeleteDuplicates;
tmp=tmp/.UndirectedEdge[x_, y_] /; x > y :> UndirectedEdge[y, x];
Table[Sort[i, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &], {i, tmp}] // DeleteDuplicates
```

which will try all vertex permutations, whose order in turn is used by `FindIndependentEdgeSet` to produce its result.

```
{{1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 6, 4 <-> 7, 5 <-> 8}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 6, 
  7 <-> 8}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 8, 4 <-> 7, 5 <-> 6}, {1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 
  3 <-> 6, 7 <-> 8}, {1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 6, 5 <-> 8}, {1 <-> 4, 
  2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 8, 5 <-> 6}, {1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 
  7 <-> 8}, {1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 8}, {1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 5, 
  3 <-> 8, 4 <-> 7}}
```

Comment: @Pjotr5: Did my answer work out for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I took so long to respond. Your code was helpful and I did use it on that day, but because it has to calculate all vertex permutations it is really only usable for relatively small graphs. I've implemented another algorithm which I found online. This algorithm goes about it in a slightly more efficient way. I've posted the code as an answer to the question.